# CakePHP Asset Compress Plugin Issues

Tags: cakephp, compression

I have a problem with using the AssetCompress plugin inside my CakePHP app. It does seem to sort of work, before is the current asset_compress.ini file. When the debug is set to 2 my site seems to find my javascript file but it is not saved into the cache folder. When I set the debug to 0 it will not work at all and says the file is missing?

I have followed the guide very closely, so what I am missing? If you need anything else from my site pasted up let me know!

```
[General]
cacheConfig = ture
alwaysEnableController = false
writeCache = true

[js]
baseUrl = http://www.MYDOMAIN.net/projects/cake/DrWho/
timestamp = false
paths[] = WEBROOT/js/*
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_js/

[css]
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_css/
[js_DataFile.js]
files[] = jquery-1.8.1.min.js
files[] = jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js
files[] = html5shiv.js
files[] = menu.js
```

Thanks Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :: You have to use a Shell to make the files, or a cake command line call when you set your debug to 0.

Now Working...